# SolrCore is loading running as Windows Service

Tags: windows, solr, windows-services, sitecore

Logged into Windows Server 2016 as Administrator, I can run Solr from the command line: `bin\solr.cmd start -p 8983 -f`

I have configured a Solr to run as a Windows Service - running as the same user, with the same command, same startup directory, etc. - however under load, the following error comes back from the upstream application (Sitecore xConnect, though this shouldn't make a difference)

```
{metadata={error-class=org.apache.solr.common.SolrException,root-error-class=org.apache.solr.common.SolrException},msg=SolrCore is loading,code=503}
```

To reiterate, everything works fine when Solr is started from the command line, only when it's run as a Windows Service does it error.

Solr version: 6.6.3
Windows version: Server 2016
Environment: AWS (m5.large EC2 instance)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the service was configured to run *without* the `-f` flag.  So the process would continually stop and re-spawn.

Answer (score 0):

Sitecore compatibility table  says to use Solr 6.6.1 with Sitecore, You should still use 6.6.2 as it fixes a bug in Solr 6.6.1 that can affect the installation of SIF. [Read here](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/227897)

I recommend you try again with Solr 6.6.2

Comment: The same issue exists when using 6.6.2

Comment: The same issue also exists using 6.6.1